# How can I create a login page which holds two buttons but one is hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a login page which holds two buttons one is hidden, when user hit on log-in button and if credential is wrong then it shows another button with clear property and when user clicks on clear then again it goes to previous one button state.

Comment: can you share a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Please add relevent code which you have done.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing demo code for your problem.

HTML code:

```
Username:<input type="text" id="user"/>Password:<input type="password" id="password"/><button id="login">Login</buton><button style="display:none" id="hidden">Clear</button>
```

here is you jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ var user=$("#user").val; var pass=$("#password").val();  $.post("ajax.php", {user: user, pass:  pass}, function(data){ if(data=="true"){ window.location.href="dashboard.php" }else{ $("#login").css("display", "none"); $("#hidden").css("display", "block"); } }); });  $("#hidden").click(function(){ $("#user").val=""; $("#password").val=""; });
```

And Lastly on ajax.php check for the credentials

```
$user = $_POST['user']; $pass=$_POST['pass'];
```

Now check the credentials by using normal login code and if it credential is right then echo "true"; so it can check in jQuery code.

Comment: Thanks for your sugg!
But I am doing this in servlet can you plz help me

Comment: sorry, I m not much familiar  with Java. But I think jquery code is same for every technology. May be not.